# Eclipse Web application deployment problem with Maven on JBoss

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I have the following pom.xml (see below) for building a web-app on JBoss. I run maven like this :

> > mvn clean compile war:exploded jboss:hard-undeploy jboss:hard-deploy jboss:start-and-wait

Every goals run fine until i hit jboss:start-and-wait goal :\ JBoss refuses to start.
I got the following error :

```
(...)
[INFO] [jboss:start-and-wait {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Starting JBoss...
[INFO] Waiting to retrieve JBoss JMX MBean connection...
[INFO] Waiting to retrieve JBoss JMX MBean connection...
[INFO] Waiting to retrieve JBoss JMX MBean connection...
[INFO] Waiting to retrieve JBoss JMX MBean connection...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unable to get JBoss JMX MBean connection: null

org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.rmi.RMIAdaptor
(...)
```

By activating the DEBUG option on maven, i detected that the root cause is a ClassNotFoundException
org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.rmi.RMIAdaptor. Why do I get this exception since my pom.xml
*does* contain org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.rmi.RMIAdaptor in the jmx-adaptor-plugin jar dependency ?
Using jboss-all-client jar as dependency gives no more results.

What am I missing ?

Stephan

**Configuration**

```
Maven 2.2.1
JBoss 5.1.0.GA
JBoss Maven Plugin 1.5.0
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.company.foo</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>foo-webapp</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
    <!-- JSF 2.0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3-b02</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3-b02</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Primefaces -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
       <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
       <!-- <version>3.0.M1</version> -->
       <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
       <artifactId>redmond</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Others -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.company.record</groupId>
       <artifactId>record-dao</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Postgresql -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
       <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
       <version>8.3-606.jdbc4</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>jboss</groupId>
       <artifactId>jmx-adaptor-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <finalName>foo.war</finalName>
  <plugins>

   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <useCache>false</useCache>
     <!-- Prevent a bug from plugin (see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MWAR-248) -->
     <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <configuration>
    <fileName>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</fileName>
    <serverName>web</serverName>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

  </plugins>
 </build>
 (...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding it to your plugin dependencies:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <configuration>
    <fileName>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</fileName>
    <serverName>web</serverName>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-client</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>5.1.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I have updated your answer with the error i get : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/proxy/Interceptor

Comment: Try replacing the dependency with jboss-all-client

Comment: New error : org.jboss.util.id.GUID; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3289509836244263718, local class serialVersionUID = 6926421946503004889; I don't know if this jar for JBoss 5.1.0.GA is in maven repo.

Comment: Are you using the following dependency?<dependency>
 <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
 <artifactId>jboss-as-client</artifactId>
 <type>pom</type>
 <version>5.1.0.GA</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: Thx for your help it runs fine now !